# How to quick format a disk using command line in MacOS

Tags: macos

I am trying to format a disk partition using just the command line. I am using the `diskutil eraseVolume` command, but it does not have the option to do quick format. is there another way to format a disk using command line that supports quick format?

Answer (score 1):

A "quick format" just deletes the directory to point to where all the files are stored, much like the index of a book.  It does not actually delete the contents.

`diskutil eraseVolume` or `diskutil reformat` does not allow for quick formatting from the command-line.

I'm sorry, but "No" is the only answer, I wish there was a better one.